# Is it possible to not buffer docker compose output when a health check is used?

Tags: docker-compose

Re-introduction of health checks with depends_on in docker compose is amazing.  Seriously was tired of writing health checks into every downstream container, especially things like a database initialization container.

That said, it seems as soon as I enable a health check/depends on, all output from those containers is buffered until the health check succeeds.  Worse - if the container fails to start for some reason, the output is swallowed altogether, and you have to poke around with `docker logs` to get the output.

So if I have a docker compose file something like:

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    ...
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mysql", "-u", "username", "--password=password", "-e", "show databases;" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 8640
      start_period: 20s
  ...

  health-check-check:
    image: centos:8
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    command: [ "-c", "echo \"mysql up\"" ]
    entrypoint: "bash"
```

Is there a way to get the mysql and health-check-check container output to compose stdout

- a) before the health checks are complete (i.e. unbuffered)
- b) regardless of health check success/failure

Comment: Bonus points for printing the output of the health checks to stdout while we're at it...